# How does this "simple filter" work?

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, smoothing, moving-average

I'm new to DSP, and I'm using this basic "1-pole LPF" Param Smooth filter which "smooth" param when I change it. The code is pretty simple:

```
class CParamSmooth
{
public:
    double a, b, z;

    CParamSmooth() { 
        a = 0.8; 
        b = 1. - a; 
        z = 0.; 
    }

    double Process(double in) { 
        z = (in * b) + (z * a); 
        return z; 
    }
};
```

If I try some [values](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/493e405a4ec622de) with "strong" `a` coefficients, I can see that it starts heavy on increment, then becomes smooth till "rounding" happen, setting `z = in`:

```
0 | 0.16
1 | 0.288
2 | 0.3904
3 | 0.47232
4 | 0.537856
5 | 0.590285
6 | 0.632228
7 | 0.665782
8 | 0.692626
9 | 0.714101
10 | 0.731281
11 | 0.745024
12 | 0.75602
13 | 0.764816
14 | 0.771853
15 | 0.777482
16 | 0.781986
17 | 0.785588
18 | 0.788471
19 | 0.790777
20 | 0.792621
21 | 0.794097
22 | 0.795278
23 | 0.796222
24 | 0.796978
25 | 0.797582
26 | 0.798066
27 | 0.798453
28 | 0.798762
29 | 0.79901
30 | 0.799208
31 | 0.799366
32 | 0.799493
33 | 0.799594
34 | 0.799675
35 | 0.79974
36 | 0.799792
37 | 0.799834
38 | 0.799867
39 | 0.799894
40 | 0.799915
41 | 0.799932
42 | 0.799946
43 | 0.799956
44 | 0.799965
45 | 0.799972
46 | 0.799978
47 | 0.799982
48 | 0.799986
49 | 0.799989
50 | 0.799991
51 | 0.799993
52 | 0.799994
53 | 0.799995
54 | 0.799996
55 | 0.799997
56 | 0.799998
57 | 0.799998
58 | 0.799998
59 | 0.799999
60 | 0.799999
61 | 0.799999
62 | 0.799999
63 | 0.799999
64 | 0.8
65 | 0.8
66 | 0.8
...
```

So, basically, each iteration is a sum of `0.16` + `prev z * 0.8`. And here is where I don't understand: why `0.16` + `prev z * 0.8` can't go "over" 0.8?

In fact, this become stable when `z = in`. Without rounding, `z` will always be < `in`. Why it can't go `> in`?

It's a sum on each iteration... who limits it?

Comment: You might want to try to compute the values by hand, drawing them on an axis one by one. Each iteration is computing a weighted mean between the previous result and the input, and with constant input it can be easy to get why you can't cross it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In more standard DSP terms, you have the following filter:

$$
y[n] = (1-a) x[n] + a y[n-1]
$$

where $x[n]$ and $y[n]$ are the input and output signals at time $n$ respectively.

The transfer function (which you didn't ask for) is:

$$
H(z) = \frac{1-a}{1 - az^{-1}}
$$

so here is your single pole, at $z=a$ in the complex plane. This filter is also known as [exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing), [exponential moving average (EMA), or exponentially weighted moving average (EWMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average).

The infinite impulse response is $h[n] = (1-a) u[n] a^n$. In layman terms, when the input signal is 0 except for $x[0]=1$, the output signal is an exponential $(1-a) \times a^n$ starting at $n=0$.

What you want is the step response (i.e. what happens if the input signal is a constant $K$ starting at time $n=0$).

In this case, the output signal is the convolution $h \star Ku$ of the impulse response and the step signal. This is (for time $n \ge 0$):

$$
y[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n} K \times h[k] = K(1-a) \sum_{k=0}^{k=n} a^k
= K(1-a)\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}
= K (1-a^{n+1})
$$

As the time $n$ grows, $a^{n+1}$ vanishes, and the step response grows monotonically to its limit value $y = K$, which is the value of the input signal.

This is what you get in your simulation.

Comment: I dared to add a few more common names for this filter, to help find literature. Corrections welcome

Comment: Beautiful answer !

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well, for step: "This filter is also known as exponential smoothing, exponential moving average (EMA), or exponentially weighted moving average (EWMA)." The formula you have put (`y[n] = (1−a)*x[n] + a*y[n−1]`) is like my formula, but the one on the wiki is different: its `y[n] = a*x[n] + (1-a)*y[n-1]`. Why?

Comment: @markzzz The difference is just in how you name your parameters. In the answer above, the exponent is a. In the wikipedia article notation, the exponent is (1-a_wiki).

Comment: Right! Thanks! So basically, the formula become `z = in - (in - z)*a` and it subtracts from `in` (step by step) an amount smaller at each step, till at some points (due to computer rounding) `(in - z)*a` become 0, so `in`. Is it right? If it wasn't "rounding", it really was a "infinite response", without returning `in`...! Not sure if that's correct anyway hehehe

Comment: @Juancho: For a long time, I could not find a book or anything else that described exponential smoothing as well as above. Even your casual  definition of step response is the best I've seen and I've looked. But recently I went back to an old book that I hadn't looked at in a looooooooong time and lot of what you say is in there in various places. If you don't have it, you would like it so link is below.  https://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=9780486495927

Comment: Isn't that exponential averager also known as "leaky integrator", see [here](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/72.php) for example? If so, you might want to add this name to the list of common names.