# Stable digital filter with leading zeroes

Tags: filter-design, infinite-impulse-response, stability

I'm looking construct a stable pole-only filter where the feedback coefficients start with a block of zeroes, i.e.

\begin{align}
a_0 &= 1\\
a_i &= 0, \textrm{ for}\ 1 \le i \lt k\\
a_i &\in\mathbb{R}, \textrm{ for}\ k \le i \le n
\end{align}

For $k = n$, this is a single-tap feedback delay, e.g.

$$
y_i = x_i + a_k y_{i - k}
$$

which is stable as long as $|a_k| < 1$.

However, I'm looking for a way to construct such filters with arbitrary $k$ and $n$.  Are there conditions or constraints that would let me construct this?

Comment: A notational note: the feedback coefficients are usually denoted as $a_k$, while the feedforward coefficients (the numerator of the transfer function) are $b_k$. Just pointing it out to avoid confusion.

Comment: An easy solution would be to take any stable polynomial with roots within the unit circle and replace $z$ with $z^k$. Your single step would also be an example of this. However this will mean that between every none zero coefficient you get $k-1$ zeroes.

Comment: @JasonR - thanks, I got turned around there.

Comment: @fibonatic - yeah, I was hoping it would be "dense" (for some hand-wavy definition of that).  That's a neat trick, though.

Comment: @JasonR I couldn't say the same, as I found out that some use `a/b`, others `b/a`. Personally, I learned `a/b`, both in mathematics and filters, so this may be a case of preference, or previous learning.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is a bit of an intuitive argument so I'm not 100% sure about it, and it's totally sideways to the way I normally think about filters, but:

Let's consider the "feedback kernel" ($a_k ... a_n$ - so, **not** including $a_0$) as an FIR filter. If the magnitude of that kernel in the frequency domain is $< 1$ including inter-bin peaks, the original filter should be stable.

If so: to construct a filter: one could generate a random set of $a_k ... a_n$, find the maximum freq response of that feedback kernel, and scale such that the peak is less than 1, to get a stable feedback kernel.

---

To reason about this: let's construct an infinite sequence of sequences, $Y^k$:

$$
Y^0_i = a_0x_i\\
Y^j_i = -\sum_{l=k}^na_lY^{j - 1}_{i - l}
$$

That is, each $Y^j$ is the previous $Y^{j - 1}$ convolved with our feedback kernel (the negation doesn't affect the argument).  I also think it's true that:

$$y_i = \sum_j Y^j_i$$

Let's say $x_i$ is "time-bounded" (zero outside a finite range) - it follows inductively that every $Y^j$ is also time-bounded, because it's a convolution of the previous.

Let's also say that the feedback kernel's transfer function has magnitude $< G$ for all frequencies.  This guarantees that whatever the input, the total energy in each $Y^k$ is strictly less than $G$ times the previous one.  This implies a geometrically-decreasing upper bound on the magnitude of the sample values of $Y^j$ as well.

This geometric progression of bounds means that when we sum up $y_i$ it converges if $G < 1$, and to a value bounded by $K/(1 - G)$ for some $K$.  The time-boundedness means that it decays over time (hand-waving over the formalism here).

---

Does this hold up?

Comment: Why do you think that the peak frequency domain magnitude of the $z$- transform of the denominator polynomial is related to stability? What's important is the root locations of the denominator polynomial. They must all be within the unit circle.

Comment: Not the whole polynomial (including $a_0$) - I'm looking at the kernel produced by removing $a_0$.  It's a bit of a weird argument which focuses largely on the time-domain, which is why I'm unsure about it.

Comment: Hi: assuming my notation interp is correct ( my backgound is not EE so I didn't understand the other answers which doesn't mean they're wrong ), what you wrote is actually a delayed exponential smoothing model: $y_{t} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{k}^{i} x_{t-k-i}$. Someone named juancho gave a beautiful EE explanation of this model. I wouldn't do it justice so I'll find the link. it's below. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/33858/how-does-this-simple-filter-work/33862#33862. But it sounds like you may want something more complex with more than one parameter.

Comment: Last thing and still only matters if you're interested: Note that my notation changed your $i$ to $t$ and my $i$ took on a different meaning.

Comment: Notice that models are not quite equivalent because the link I referred to considers the case where the coefficients sum to 1. but the concept is the same and equivalence can be obtained by introducing a second parameter to your model.  if interested, google for "koyck distributed lag".

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a polynomial of the form

$$
p(x) = x^n + \sum_{m = 0}^{n-k-1} a_m\,x^m \tag{1}
$$

whose roots lie inside the unit circle. For a sufficiently large value for $|x|$ the $x^n$ term will always dominate over all the other terms. Since $|x^n| \neq 0$ for $|x|$ larger then this sufficiently large value, therefore $|p(x)| \neq 0$ for these values of $x$ as well. This implies that all the roots of $p(x)$ need to be contained inside this region of $|x|$ smaller then this sufficiently large value.

So in this case we want this region to be the unit circle, so at $|x| = 1$ the term $x^n$ should dominate. An upper bound at $|x| = 1$ for absolute value of the sum of the remaining terms would be $|\vec{a}|_1$; the 1-norm of the vector containing the coefficients of $a_m$ from $(1)$. So as long as $|\vec{a}|_1 \ll 1$ one can be sure that $(1)$ does not have any roots outside the unit circle. For this you can start with any vector $\vec{v}$ and scale it using

$$
\vec{a} = \alpha\frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|_1} \tag{2}
$$

with $0<|\alpha| \ll 1$.

This does not really use the fact that there are $k-1$ zero coefficients. I suspect that as $k$ becomes larger the constraint $|\vec{a}|_1 \ll 1$ (and thus $|\alpha| \ll 1$) can become less and less strict, since $x^n$ starts to dominate faster. At least for $\vec{v}$ generated from a Gaussian distribution $\alpha = 0.9$ seems to work for a very large majority, at least for the combinations $n$ and $k$ that I tested.