# The Spectrum of the Impulse Response of Linear Time Invariant (LTI) System

Tags: linear-systems, dsp-core

Consider an LTI system with impulse response 
$$h[n] = \frac{1}{5^n} u[n].$$

(a) Determine and sketch the magnitude and phase response $|H(\omega)|$ and $\arg(H(\omega))$ respectively.

(b) Determine and sketch the magnitude and phase spectra for the input and outPUt
signals for the following inputs:

1. $x[n] = \cos(6\pi n/10)$ for $-\infty < n < \infty$
2. $x[n] = \{ ... ,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1, ... \}$
                          |

Comment: Can I please ask what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

For part a,

given the impulse response as $$h[n] = \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)^n u[n] $$ its frequency response is the DTFT of $h[n]$ which is:

$$ h[n] = \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)^n u[n] \implies H(\omega) = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{5} e^{-j\omega} } $$

For the part b,

you must use the **convolution** property which says that:
$$ y[n] = x[n] \star h[n] \implies Y(\omega) = X(\omega) H(\omega) $$

Comment: thanx , but what about  the magnitude and phase of H(w)

Comment: $H(\omega)$ is a complex valued function So you can plot its magnitude and phase just as if you were computing the magnitude and phase of an ordinary complex number, but, for each $\omega$ instead of a single one.

Comment: Fat32: There's another question with a similar result and they call it the transfer function but use z instead. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/33858/how-does-this-simple-filter-work. is it correct to say that when $z$ is used, it's referred to as the transfer function and when $e^{jw}$ is used, it's referred to as the frequency response ? As you can tell, I find the terminology confusing. thanks.

Comment: FAt32: I ask this question because I

Comment: have one book where they use poliynomials in z to obtain the output. but there's also this approach that you talk about here. clearly, the 2 approaches must be equivalent but maybe there are cases where one is easier to use than the other or one is inappropriate. thanks.

Comment: @markleeds That's true. $H(z)$ / $H(s)$ are called as the Transfer Functions of a discrete/cont LTI systems and $H(\Omega)$ / $H(e^{j\omega})$ are the frequency responses.

Comment: @markleeds they are not equivalent. The transfer function is more general. It applies for stable and unstable systems. Frequency response is only valid for stable systems. Frequency response can only be used for steady state behaviour whereas the transfer function can also be used for transient analysis.